# 'static functions with block scope are illegal' error for compiling Zeus

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I want to compile Z[eus source code](https://github.com/Visgean/Zeus) on Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2010 I receive this error 'static functions with block scope are illegal', is there any way to force compiler to ignore this error? (One friend of mine compiled this source code without any modification with my current setup)
[to compile the source first you should change path of compiler in 'make/buildconfig.inc.php' file) [I am a researcher], This is the simplest case study I think:

```
int main() {
    static int func1();   // C2267
}
```

This is the function

```
static bool unhookList(HANDLE process, HOOKWINAPI *list, DWORD count)
{
  bool ok = true; 
  for(DWORD i = 0; i < count; i++)if(list[i].originalFunction != NULL)
  {
    if(!WaHook::_unhook(process, list[i].functionForHook, list[i].originalFunction, list[i].originalFunctionSize))
    {
      ok = false;
#     if defined WDEBUG1
      WDEBUG1(WDDT_ERROR, "Failed to unhook WinApi at index %u", i);
#     endif
    }
    /*else
    {
      PeImage::_repalceImportFunction(coreData.modules.current, list[i].originalFunction, list[i].functionForHook);
      Core::replaceFunction(list[i].originalFunction, list[i].functionForHook);
    }*/
  }
  return ok;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] of the failing code?

Comment: @NathanOliver Unfortunately it is not an small project, and I think I can not provide a very well case but I provided simplest form

Comment: Have you tried asking your friend what they did to build the project? That might be the quickest way to resolve your problem.

Comment: @RSahu I do not have access to him

Answer (score 1):

Declaring functions within a block scope is illegal in C and C++. So, what exactly are you trying to do? If you just want to call the function unhookList(), declared in one of the Zeus headers, then simply call it like this:

```
int main() {
    // parameter values are just for example
    bool result = unhookList(0, NULL, 1);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever compiled that?